# Displaying a list like a list

Tags: html, css

I Have a `List` which isn't diplaying like a `list`, I want every `<li>` to be under the other, just like a standard list.

Here is an example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/w5tZ3/

Comment: Because you are using `float`? http://jsfiddle.net/w5tZ3/3/

Answer (score 6):

```
#settingNev li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    clear:both;
}
```

add clear both to show as list

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the list in horizontal way, please don't use float:left;

Answer (score 0):

**Clearing floats** is your Answer Use `clear:both;` Or `overflow:hidden`

```
#settingNev li {
  overflow:hidden       /*Add this to the make li in flow*/ 
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}
```

For more Detail Refer [**This**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left;` from `a` and `span` styles

Answer (score 0):

I added the following patch to your CSS.

```
#settingNev ul {
    display:table !important;    
}

#settingNev ul li {
    display:table-row !important;
}
```

Here is the entire code mate:

http://jsfiddle.net/w5tZ3/9/